# grouping objects by time gap

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have this very complex series of linq queries that does everything I need it to do except one thing.

First let me explain what this does.

This series of queries takes data about a gaming conference and concatenates the `EventSession.SessionEventName` based on the same `gameID` and the same `SessionDate`.

So, in the view, it would look like this:

```
    GameID    | GameName    | Names            | PlayDate     | PlayDuration
    123         Pac-Man       Joe; Jim; Mary     10/1/2018      10:00 AM - 12:30 PM
```

So this is all working fine, EXCEPT...I need to add this to the query, and I can't figure out where to put it or how to do it:

I need to add a condition, that separates the rows IF there is more than 35 minutes between games on the same date.

For example, the above would look like this if there was more than 35 minutes between the playing of Joe, Jim, or Mary.

```
    EventID | GameID    | GameName    | Names            | PlayDate     | PlayDuration
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1      123         Pac-Man       Joe; Jim           10/1/2018      10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
       2      123         Pac-Man       Mary               10/1/2018      11:40 AM - 12:30 PM
```

So basically, it groups the players together if it's the same GameID and PlayDate.  However, if there's a 35+ minute gap anywhere, it will split into a new row grouping.

I'm at a loss of how to do this.

I'd appreciate any and all advice.

Thanks!

Here is my controller method that contains this magic mess of code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchByDate(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {

        // create a list of conferenceGames
        var conferenceGames = await _context.PublisherList
                     .Where(m => m.MakerCatalogId != null
                     && !m.IsBetaStatus).ToListAsync();

        // create a list of conferencePlayers
        var conferencePlayers = await _context.PlayerList
            .Where(p => p.PlayerTypeId == 23
            && p.PlayerStartTime != null
            && p.PlayerEndTime != null)
            .OrderBy(p => p.PlayerStartTime).ToListAsync();

        // create a list of conferenceSponsers
        var conferenceSponsers = await _context.SponserList
            .Where(f => f.SponserDateTimeStart >= start 
            && f.SponserDateTimeStart <= end
            && f.PublisherId != 2000111
            ).ToListAsync();

        // create an IEnumerable of EventSession 
        var query = from cp in conferencePlayers
                    join cs in conferenceSponsers on cp.SponserId equals cs.SponserId
                    join cg in conferenceGames on cs.PublisherId equals cg.PublisherId
                    select new EventSession
                    {
                        Id = cp.PlayerId,
                        GameId = cg.PublisherId,
                        SessionGameName = cg.GameDisplayName,
                        SessionEventName = cp.PlayerDisplayName,
                        SessionDate = cs.SponserDateTimeStart,
                        SessionStartTime = cp.PlayerStartTime.Value.TimeOfDay,
                        SessionEndTime = cp.PlayerEndTime.Value.TimeOfDay
                    };

        // order the results
        var orderedResults = query
            .OrderBy(n => n.GameId)
            .ThenBy(d => d.SessionDate)
            .ThenBy(tsa => tsa.SessionStartTime)
            .ToList();

        // group the List by Date and Game
        List<GroupedEvents> playersGroupList = orderedResults.GroupBy(x => new { x.SessionDate, x.GameId }).Select(group => new GroupedEvents
        {
            GameName = group.Select(n => n.SessionGameName).FirstOrDefault(),
            GameId = group.Select(c => c.GameId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
            PlayDate = group.Select(d => d.SessionDate).FirstOrDefault(),
            Names = String.Join(" ; ", group.Select(g => g.SessionEventName).ToArray()),
            PlayDuration = group.Select(g => g.SessionStartTime).First() + " - " + group.Select(g => g.SessionEndTime).Last(),
        }).ToList();

        // return the ordered/grouped list back to the view
        return View(playersGroupList);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you change data names from e.g. `PlayerDisplayName` to `SessionEventName`? Is that 35 minutes between the end of one and the beginning of another?

Comment: @NetMage I think I changed names by accident at some point and just kept it.  Yes, it is from the end of one to the beginning of another one. So, SessionEndTime to SessionStartTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some extension methods, this can be done fairly understandably.

First, a variation of `Aggregate` that is a version of the APL scan operator travels along an `IEnumerable` returning the intermediate results, but this variation combines a pair at a time, current and previous item:

```
// TKey combineFn((TKey Key, T Value) CurKeyItem, T nextItem):
// CurKeyItem.Key = Current Key
// CurKeyItem.Value = Current Item
// NextItem = Next Item
// returns (Key, Current Item)
public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanToPairs<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combineFn) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator())
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var curkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

            while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                yield return curkv;
                curkv = (combineFn(curkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
            }
            yield return curkv;
        }
}
```

Explanation: `ScanToPairs` goes through the `IEnumerable` starting with the first and second values and the seedKey value. It passes a `ValueTuple` containing the current Key and current item and (separately) next item to a combineFn, and yields a `ValueTuple` of Key, current item. So the first result is (seedKey, FirstItem). The second result will be (combineFn((seedKey, FirstItem), SecondItem), SecondItem). And so on.

Then, a `GroupBy` operator that groups by testing pairs with a boolean test function:

```
// bool testFn(T prevItem, T curItem)
// returns groups by runs of matching bool
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByPairsWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> testFn) =>
    src.ScanToPairs(1, (kvp, cur) => testFn(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
       .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Explanation: Using the `ScanToPairs` method, this method groups the `IEnumerable` into tuples where the key is an integer starting with `1` representing the number of the run of `true` `testFn` results from comparing the previous item to the current item. Once all the runs have been numbered, they are grouped together with `GroupBy` into groups of the items that belong to a run.

With these helpers, it is relatively straightforward. Add a `SelectMany` after the first grouping to break up each group into sub-groups by the time based condition:

```
var playersGroupList = orderedResults.GroupBy(x => new { x.SessionDate, x.GameId })
                                     .SelectMany(g => g.GroupByPairsWhile((p, c) => c.SessionStartTime-p.SessionEndTime <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(35)))
                                     .Select(group => new GroupedEvents {
                                         GameName = group.Select(n => n.SessionGameName).FirstOrDefault(),
                                         GameId = group.Select(c => c.GameId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                                         PlayDate = group.Select(d => d.SessionDate).FirstOrDefault(),
                                         Names = String.Join("; ", group.Select(g => g.SessionEventName).ToArray()),
                                         PlayDuration = group.Select(g => g.SessionStartTime).First() + " - " + group.Select(g => g.SessionEndTime).Last(),
                                     })
                                     .ToList();
```

So, the `SelectMany` takes each group on a given `SessionDate`, and sub-groups them into runs where each member is less than 35 minutes from the next. Because of `SelectMany`, the sub-groups are all promoted to be the groups of the final result. So now you have groups where each one contains a run of sessions where there are less than 35 minutes from `SessionEndTime` to next `SessionStartTime`. Note that a run will end at the end of the day regardless, so if you might have runs that go across midnight, you would need to change the grouping.

Note: If it is possible for sessions starting at the same time to have different durations (i.e. end times) then you need to add a `ThenBy(tsa => tsa.SessionEndTime)` to your `orderedResults` sorting.

Comment: I think this might be working but I'm not sure how.  How do ScanToPairs and GroupByPairsWhile work together in order to create the listing I need?  Thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I'm not sure I can adequately explain here, but I will attempt to add more explanation. I suggest using LINQPad and its `Dump` method to analyze what each step is doing.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I have added some more explanation of how the methods work. Please let me know if you have any questions (PS `ScanToPairs` and `GroupByPairsWhile` are part of my LINQPad library of `IEnumerable` extensions that generalize processing of runs and groups.)